# Absolute position divs with javascript/css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got this PSD design I need to code to HTML and it has a slideshow with navigation buttons next and previous in the sides of browser window (left and right), so I guess you could just do CSS `position: absolute` for both divs, one to `left: 0`; and other to `right: 0`; but they would stay in the sides at the top of the browser screen and according to the design they have to be in the middle of the browser's screen vertical height. So what I mean is basically e.g using jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZVL8W/ Take these blocks:
[image]

And position them like this:
[image]

So I was wondering there would be probably javascript included since those divs would be inside some deep div structure that has set width, so the slideshow control divs would somehow need to be able to move out from the set width of parent containers.

Comment: set both position: absolute; and the left-box get left: 0; and the other one right: 0;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/ZVL8W/3/
This has equal height no matter what the screen size is.

```
 .left-box {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: red;
        display: block;
        position:absolute;
        top:50%;
        left:0px;
        margin-top:-50px;
    }
    .right-box {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: blue;
        display: block;
        position:absolute;
        top:50%;
        right:0px;
        margin-top:-50px;
    }
```

Comment: So this will work as long as I don't set the parent container position to relative with fixed width?

Answer (score 2):

you can do it all by CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/ZVL8W/7/

```
.left-box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-50px;
    left:0;
}
.right-box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    left:100%;
    margin-left:-100px;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-50px;
}
```

Comment: This would not center vertically, which is one of his requirements